# How to loop through column in php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Currently I have a table with several columns with names such as A1, A2, A3 etc and I've found that doing it this way no longer works with the new database structure I want to use.

The A1, A2, A3.. will now be listed within the actual column.

I have included the current code I am, using to get this information, but I don't know how to loop through the column there the A1, A2.. are and get the information on the same row.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php     
  $i=1;            
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);    
  while ($i < 6)    {
      if($row["A".$i.""]=='FREE')        {
          print "<td><p>Available</p></td>";
      }
      else {
               if($row["A$i"]==$auth_user) {
                   echo $i;
                   print"<td><div align=\"center\">".$row["A". $i. ""];
                   print "<br /><p>Cancel</p></span>";
                   print "</div></td>";
               }
               else {
                        print"<td><div align=\"center\">".$row["A". $i. ""];
                        print "</div></td>";
                    }
           }
           $i++;
        }
    }
?>
```

Any pointers would be great.

Current Table Structure:

```
Date         | A1   |  A2   ...
---------------------------
2017-05-23   | John |  FREE ...
2017-05-24   | Jack |  FREE ...
2017-05-25   | Jane |  John ...
2017-05-26   | FREE |  Jack ...
```

New Table Structure:

```
Date         | Session   |  User ...
------------------------------------
2017-05-23   | A1        |  John ...
2017-05-23   | A2        |  Jane ...
2017-05-23   | A4        |  John ...
2017-05-23   | A9        |  Jack ...
```

Comment: Including an example of a few of the rows would be helpful.

Comment: The ... is more confusing.  Show me the structure of the result set that will be looped .  In other words, help me to fill the $row input variable in my answer.  Or are you returning more than one row?

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for the reply. The sql query is to query and return everything with the A1, a2 etc value within the session and the print on screen the user on a1, a2 etc

Comment: @SHC Look, I want to help you, and I have the necessary skill, but you are not giving me the necessary ingredients to bake this cake.  Tell me the data that is coming out of the query, and don't express the data to me with "..." or "etc."  You can alter your actual data to keep it private, but I need to know the entire resultset.  How many columns are coming through?  How many rows?  I simply don't know enough to provide a quality answer.  Is `FREE` gone now from the data?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you only trying to process one row of data in your resultset.  If there are multiple rows, you will need to write a loop for the rows.

If you use `mysqli_fetch_row()`, then you will get an array of results with 0-indexed keys which will help you by removing the need to identify specific column names.  As for how you are going to identify `Free` and `$auth_user`, that can not be determined without you providing some sample input to your question.

I'll provide some fake input for demonstration purposes:

```
$auth_user=1;
$row=['something',1,2,'somethingelse','Free'];
// $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Method:

```
foreach($row as $v){
    if($v=='Free'){
        echo '<td><p>Available</p></td>';
    }else{
        echo "<td><div align=\"center\">$v";
        if($v==$auth_user){
            echo '<br /><p>Cancel</p>';  // removed closing span tag
        }
        echo '</div></td>';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    <td><div align="center">something</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">1<br /><p>Cancel</p></div></td>
    <td><div align="center">2</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">somethingelse</div></td>
    <td><p>Available</p></td>
```

---

Keep in mind, I am making an assumption about input data.  If my sample input doesn't resemble the kind of data you are handling please update your question and leave me a comment so I know to adjust my answer.

Answer (score -2):

From your $results set you can call the fetch_field method as shown at  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php

```
$query = "SELECT Name, SurfaceArea from Country ORDER BY Code LIMIT 5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* Get field information for all columns */
    while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {

        printf("Name:     %s\n", $finfo->name);
        printf("Table:    %s\n", $finfo->table);
        printf("max. Len: %d\n", $finfo->max_length);
        printf("Flags:    %d\n", $finfo->flags);
        printf("Type:     %d\n\n", $finfo->type);
    }
    $result->close();
}

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
```

Works on statement too using method meta_data http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php